# The 404 not found image is not unique

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This site's `404 not found` image is not unique. It's shared with Pro Webmasters SE and Photography SE.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/404
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/404
https://photo.stackexchange.com/404

It's entirely possible that this is intentional, but since most sites don't have the same image, I thought it was reasonable to suspect that it was a bug.

Sister bug reports:
[on Meta Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367/the-404-not-found-image-is-not-unique)
[on Meta Photography](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/518/the-404-not-found-image-is-not-unique)